# Rails AJAX jQuery POST - param not passed and database not updating

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, coffeescript

I am new to Rails and having a rough time trying to update or post to my database with AJAX. I see in my development log that the following code queries the database, but the data is not passed as a param to the controller action, and the database is not updated, although I'm able to get to the `flascard_id`, "yes" and "success" alerts below through jQuery.

`user_flashcards.js.coffee`

```
("div.user_flashcards_form").click ->
    slide_number = $('.flexslider').data('flexslider').currentSlide + 1
    flashcard_id = $("img:eq("+slide_number+")").data("flashcard-id")
    alert(flashcard_id)
    if !@checked    
    alert("yes")
    $.ajax({
        url: "/user_flashcards/" + flashcard_id + "/mark",
        type: "POST",
        data:   { marked: @checked },
        success: (data) ->
            alert ("success")
            return false
        error:(data) ->
    return false
     })
    else
        alert("no")
    return
```

`user_flashcards_controller.rb`

```
def mark
  @flashcard_id = params[:id]
  user_id = current_user.id
  @user_flashcard = UserFlashcards.where(flashcard_id: @flashcard_id, user_id: user_id).first_or_create
  if @user_flashcard
    @user_flashcard.update(marked: params[:marked])
  end
end
```

Comment: Is the @user_flashcard object found or created in your mark method?

Comment: The @user_flashcard instance variable is created in the mark method.

Comment: I changed '@checked' to the boolean 'true' and the param is sent and the database is updating. The problem is now how to correctly pass whether or not the checkbox is checked. I will work on it more and update.

Comment: I changed @checked to $('input#mark.flashcard_mark_checkbox.checkbox').is(:checked) and the code is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I changed @checked to
>   $('input#mark.flashcard_mark_checkbox.checkbox').is(:checked) and the
>   code is working.

Problem here is you're relying on a `checkbox` input to pass data to your controller

--

[Checkboxes don't have a value if they are unchecked (at least to JQuery's Serialize method)](http://tdanemar.wordpress.com/2010/08/24/jquery-serialize-method-and-checkboxes/):

> So while you may expect a query string like:
>
> `'checkbox1=true&checkbox2=false'`
>
> What you’ll actually get is:
>
> `'checkbox1='`

What I imagine is happening for you is if the checkbox is not checked, you're getting a blank, or no, param sent to the controller. Of course, this won't register any data. I would do this:

```
def mark
  @flashcard_id = params[:id]
  user_id = current_user.id
  marked = params[:marked] || "0"

  @user_flashcard = UserFlashcards.where(flashcard_id: @flashcard_id, user_id: user_id).first_or_create
  if @user_flashcard
    @user_flashcard.update(marked: marked)
  end
end
```

This will give a default value for `marked`, which *should* allow you to save it to the db correctly